# How realistic is the tornadoes in Into the storm 2014

Tags: realism, into-the-storm

Specifically Pete, when he flew inside the tornado in his car. Can it be possible to survive such an extremely high fall like that.

Comment: I just wanted to point out that your tag is spelled incorrectly as "into-the-strom". I do not have enough reputation to create the correct tag.

Answer (score 3):

Into the Storm depicted multiple individuals not only being sucked into the tornadoes, but getting pulled in a spiral up the funnels. This is wrong on most every count. While tornadoes do, in fact, pull on objects, they generally toss them at an apogee, rather than pulling them inside. This is especially true for sizable objects, such as humans.

Additionally, the film has other anachronisms, such as making tornadoes appear to be identical in structure to hurricanes, with the most notable example being the eye. The eye of a tornado is not serene like a hurricane and does not involve a clear sky, as a tornado takes place beneath storm clouds.

While not perfect by any standard, including science, Twister (1996) is actually one of the more scientifically-accurate tornado blockbusters.

Answer (score 1):

You do not twirl up and out of a tornado, the winds cannot take you up that far. Yes, they can throw you a distance from where you originally began. The most likely case is being tossed around in all kinds of directions, with debris flying by you.

Despite all the movies about tornados sucking people up, the real fact is that the winds from the tornado will throw you a distance and not pull you towards it. The realism of Into the Storm is not very accurate. While some people can survive being picked up and thrown by tornados it is very rare. Source: http://www.wunderground.com/resources/severe/tornado_myths.asp